# Paypal Sendbox is stuck

Tags: paypal

I recently added a plugin on my website which has a payment system.
This plugin asks for PayPal Client ID and Secret to test the payment system through sandbox.

As per the instructions, I created a business and a buyer account. To be sure, the business in US and buyer in India.
I used the plugin and reached the payment page, where I entered Buyer's credentials and logged in.

The next page, asked me to enter Credit card details and I added it.
When I pressed "Add" button to add credit card, nothing happened and the payment stuck.

Please help me with the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue as of today

> Initial Notification: We are aware of an issue preventing merchants
>   from completing payments in the sandbox environment. When attempting a
>   payment, affected merchants are receiving the error: "Please add a
>   debit or credit card to complete your purchase." We are actively
>   working to resolve this issue.

The incident is on-going and currently there is no ETA for a fix.

https://www.paypal-status.com/incident/sandbox

**UPDATE 16th August 2018**

Issue has been fixed.

Comment: @pmewada probably - but better test it again, once the issue is resolved

Comment: @pmewada Yes, this issue only affects making payments in the sandbox environment. According to PayPals service status, there are no issues with the live environments.

Comment: Thanks for the help Bud!